# How to get message from i18n message properties using grails 2.x unit testing?

Tags: unit-testing, grails, internationalization, message

I am getting problem in getting message from I18n properties file while writting test cases in grails 2.x.

in controller i am using like this:

```
g.message(code:'upload.coverpage.file.isempty.msg')
```

when getting into result object from controller, the message will returning as :

```
upload.coverpage.file.isempty.msg
```

but original message is:

```
"Sorry, the file size is empty."
```

How to get the original message. 
any body have idea ?

Thanks & regards

arnagendla

Comment: Why g.message? You can use message(code:"...") in controller.

Comment: @Mr.Cat You don't technically _need_ the `g.` prefix but I tend to use it anyway (a) to make it clearer to anyone reading the code that I intended it to be a taglib call and (b) because of the potential for name clashes.  (b) is particularly painful in webflow, where if you assign to `flash.message` in your controller then calls to `message(...)` in your GSPs stop working (but `g.message(...)` still works fine).

Answer (score 1):

I think that this is correct way to test messages. I'm writing tests now for application that was written on grails 1.3.5 and got an error for a controller unit test:

```
No signature of method: ChallengeListingController.message()
```

I've decided to solve it this way:

```
ChallengeListingController.metaClass.message={def msg-> return msg.code}
```

I return exactly message **code**: it's enough to make a decision that the string is correct and of course you separate code from values.

Comment: hi Mr. Cat, Thanks. But Where i need to use this code? in Controller or ControllerTests?

Comment: In test of course. it adds message method to controller dynamicly. But this is for grails 1.3.5. In your test use assertEquals('upload.coverpage.file.isempty.msg', mockFlash.message) and it's rather correct to return message code than value